# Multithreading and GDB

Tags: multithreading

In a C++ multithreaded environment.There are two thread running and program gets crashed when the second thread try to access something, but the crash happen due to first thread. How can you find out that using GDB.

Answer (score 2):

Use `thread 1` and `thread 2` (or `t 1` and `t 2`) to switch between threads, and use `bt` to have the stack trace of the two. Then print some variable to guess which one is badly broken, uninitialized, out of range, etc. :)

Look at the help too. `help threads` give you hints ...

my2c